# Check for Palidrome using Recursion and Char Array search

Tags: java, arrays, function, recursion, methods

I'm currently trying to use a function that compares the left and right side character to return a true or false Boolean value as to whether the string entered by the user is a palindrome or not, but I get a vague error statement to do with line 44. Not sure how to proceed. I am a beginner-level Java programmer who is open-minded and willing to learn, so don't roast me to hard haha.

```
import java.util.Scanner;



/**
*
* @author owner
*/
public class Q2_RecursivePalidrome {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int leftSideCharacter = 0;
    int rightSideCharacter = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter word to check whether palidrome: ");
    String userInput = scan.next();
    char[] checkPalidrome = userInput.toCharArray(); // creates an array of characters

    System.out.println(isPalidrome(checkPalidrome, leftSideCharacter, rightSideCharacter));
}

public static boolean isPalidrome(char[] checkPalidrome, int leftSideCharacter, int rightSideCharacter) {
    leftSideCharacter = 0;
    rightSideCharacter = checkPalidrome.length - 1; // java arrays start at 0, not 1.
    if (rightSideCharacter > leftSideCharacter) { // check both ends of string character by character
        // to be palidrome, both sides of string should be same
        // 
        if (checkPalidrome[leftSideCharacter] == checkPalidrome[rightSideCharacter]) {
            return (isPalidrome(checkPalidrome, leftSideCharacter + 1, rightSideCharacter - 1));
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the point of passing in a value (parameter `leftSideCharacter`), then immediately throw that value away (`leftSideCharacter = 0`)? Same for `rightSideCharacter`. Perhaps those values are what you pass in from the `main` method, right?

Comment: @Andreas that was indeed the problem, I initialized them incorrectly. I'm new to coding and unfortunately wasn't overly familiar with the process of debugging, and I realized by printing the indices that change everytime you call them would've shown me that they weren't doing what I wanted them to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple main issues here, but you have the right idea:

1. Your recursive function uses left and right indices to determine which characters to compare in the test string. However, these two pointers are immediately set to the left and right ends of the string when the function is called, so they never recursively move towards the middle. Since the base case where the indices are equal is unreachable, the stack overflows. Remember, these calls are identical all the way down the stack, but with different parameters, so one-time "set up" tasks like setting initial indices should be moved outside of the recursive function.
2. Your initial pointer indices are `0, 0`. This is an inaccurate "set up" call to the recursive function--it should be `0, string.length - 1`.

Here is code that fixes these problems and cleans up comments and variable names:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Q2_RecursivePalidrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "racecar";
        System.out.println(isPalidrome(test.toCharArray(), 0, test.length() - 1));
    }

    static boolean isPalidrome(char[] test, int l, int r) {
        if (l < r) {
            if (test[l] == test[r]) {
                return isPalidrome(test, l + 1, r - 1);
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

By the way, the important lesson to take from all this is how to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). In this case, printing your indices (the arguments that change from one call to the next) at the top of your recursive function will clearly show that they aren't doing what you expect.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm not very familiar with debugging my program, and I'll try to make a habit of printing any important values that change during each call when looking for errors!